# How to print page load time only once

Tags: php

```
enter code here

    $loadMessageDisplayed = FALSE;
  function file_get_contents_curl($url){
    global $loadMessageDisplayed;
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

//PAGE LOAD TIME
    if(!curl_errno($ch) && !$loadMessageDisplayed){
            $cinfo =  curl_getinfo($ch); 
            echo 'Page loaded in '.$cinfo['total_time'].' seconds';
            $loadMessageDisplayed = TRUE;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I want to display page load time only once. Again if i call the same function it should not display me load time.

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: i could not display load time in related field (field division -> <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <?php $site=$_POST["url"];
                                          $d=file_get_contents_curl($site);  
                                    ?>
                                 </div>

Comment: When you say "only once" do you really mean only once? Or is it once per session, once per x minues or something else?

Comment: i have called that function 3times -> 1) is in page load time 2) and 3) with other field. my problem is when i am calling 2) and 3) time its printing loadtime in both fields. I don't want to print it again. so this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    //PAGE LOAD TIME
    if (!defined('constant')) {
        define('constant', 'value');

        if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
            $cinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo 'Page loaded in ' . $cinfo['total_time'] . ' seconds';
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: where to apply this ??

Comment: still not able to c in load time field